# hsqldb reports "user lacks privilege or object not found" only in memory-based database

Tags: spring-mvc, hsqldb, mybatis

Environment: Spring(3.2.3.RELEASE) + MyBatis(3.2.2) + HSQL(2.3.0)

```
<resultMap id="hashMapResult" type="java.util.HashMap">
    <result property="key" column="key" />
    <result property="value" column="value" />
</resultMap>

<select id="getSettings" resultMap="hashMapResult">
    SELECT "KEY","VALUE" from "PUBLIC"."SETTINGS";
</select>

     create table "SETTINGS" (
    "KEY" varchar(255) not null,
    "VALUE" varchar(512) not null,
    CONSTRAINT SETTINGS_KEY_UNIQUE UNIQUE("KEY")
     );
```

URL: jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mydb;sql.syntax_mys=true;shutdown=true;

When using memory database, the following errors appeared:

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: SETTINGS
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.hsqldb.SchemaManager.getTable(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableName(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableOrSubquery(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableReference(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
```

But when using file-based database jdbc:hsqldb:file:mydb;sql.syntax_mys=true;shutdown=true; no errors at all.

I am using Spring's EmbeddedDatabaseFactory to init the database:

```
    try {
        EmbeddedDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new EmbeddedDatabaseFactory();
        DatabaseConfig dbConfig = appConfig.getDbConfig();
        ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        populator.setContinueOnError(false);
        populator.setIgnoreFailedDrops(false);
        DefaultResourceLoader resourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
        populator.addScript(resourceLoader.getResource(dbConfig
                .getSqlSchemeFile()));
        populator.addScript(resourceLoader.getResource(dbConfig
                .getSqlDataFile()));
        dbFactory.setDatabasePopulator(populator);
        dbFactory.setDatabaseName(dbConfig.getName());
        dbFactory.setDatabaseConfigurer(new HSQLConfigurer(dbConfig));
        return dbFactory.getDatabase();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("dataSource error", e); //$NON-NLS-1$

        return null;
    }
```

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use shutdown=true in this context. It seems the connection is closed and the database is shutdown, which means the memory database no longer exists.

You should also avoid using VALUE as a column name. This is a keyword.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on fredt's answer

This error is reported when a column is named with a reserved word - so a column named 'count' would also fail in the same way.

For a list of reserved words (for HSQL and others) refer to this answer - [How to find if a column name is a reserved keyword across various databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058193/how-to-find-if-a-column-name-is-a-reserved-keyword-across-various-databases)